# Redux, use dispatch and don't mutate.. except for sometimes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Ok, so I'm very much new to Redux.  I'm running through the creator's 30 tutorials.  I've followed very closely so far, but here at vid 17 there's a curveball:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-react-todo-list-example-adding-a-todo

The core concepts are sold as:

- App state in its entirety is represented as a single, immutable object
- You don't mutate that state - the desire is simply expressed via calling `dispatch`

But then suddenly, in this video:

1. A global variable is used to track app state (the next ID to be added)
2. Its value is mutated directly - without dispatching an action
3. The contents of a textbox are read from/written to directly, again without using state or `dispatch`

Going on what's been said previously, I would have guessed at both the next item ID and text being a part of the app state object.

This is done without a second thought, and I'm trying to process and reason with every step introduced, and work out any significance.  There might be done, and feel free to tell me so!  But just in case, I have some guesses why this is, although they are not as "neat" as everything sold to me so far.  They mostly revolve around defining (or re-defining) "app state".  It all seems arbitrary - e.g.:

- Is it just because these "work in progress" new item state properties are simple value types?
- Because we decide that anything occurring between the defined actions are inconsequential?
- Because at some point we all secretly want to revert to being a bit lazy, and we can get away with it here?
- Because we secretly admit that at some point reducers are more verbose? :)

So, I wanted to see if there's a consensus / correct and definite answer to it - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you watch the tutorial series all the way through, he'll get rid of the id generation logic. In general, that doesn't belong in the client, anyway. And I *think* he'll get rid of the direct textbox access.

As a principle, though, you could argue that generation of an auto-increment value is a reasonable place for mutation.

As for reading and writing directly to a textbox, I'd say it's generally not the "React" way to do things. I've done it in a few custom components (e.g. for special masking reasons), but generally, you'll bind the textbox to some state value and update that value with a reducer.

There are many patterns around reading/writing input state. [Redux form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) is a popular one.

I personally use event delegation and have a single event handler per form that updates state according to the name of the input whose state/value changed. I've found that this produces the least amount of code, keeps my state update in one place via a single action and a relatively simple, but flexible reducer.